# Airbnb: gradual engagement on web app but not on mobile app - rationale ?

Tags: signup-signon, onboarding

Airbnb lets you search for places on their web app until you want to contact or book it. Then you have to create an account and go through the sign up process.

In the android app, you have to sign up upfront.

It does not make a lot of sense to me that airbnb differentiate the whole sign-up process between its web app and mobile app. Any clue?

Comment: It may be a case of different teams with different ideas of how users use the site/app. Usually that's the case, because someone who's using the web app might have a different goal than someone using the mobile app.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: this is purely speculation.

Perhaps it is due to **the differences in a user's barrier to entry**.

A website requires *far less commitment* than an application. Downloading an application can be seen as an indication of a certain level of interest, whereas a website more easily allows a user to only express a temporary commitment as a fleeting passerby.

To allow gradual engagement in the website is smart because these users have yet to express any level of commitment to the services.

Answer (score 0):

Because if someone installs the Airbnb's native app, it means he/she is most likely an already existing user, in which case it's much easier to pursue many actions logged in, for both parties.

Comment: That isn't necessarily true I've downloaded many apps that I wasn't an existing user for. Perhaps "more likely" to be an existing user is a better way to say it.

Comment: @DasBeasto you're right. Just changed. I was also meaning more in the context of airbnb, since it's a web service with fully functioning website (unlike the apps you installed probably) AND it's something you do important things with such as renting out your home, so you want to first try it out cause you're more conservative...